# Is there a way to remove line under ics spinner in Actionbar Sherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, spinner

Is there a way to remove the gray divider line under the spinner? (The one to the left of the bottom right arrow)
Is it some kind of shadow effect applied as a Style?

and defined as follows:

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_settings_more"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
></com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found out the answer. basically all I had to do was change to Spinner's background like this:
    android:background="@drawable/abs__spinner_ab_holo_light"

which is a selector defined by Sherlock ActionBar

hope this helps someone